# Why doesn't objectify's put() function throw exception?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, put, objectify

GAE native put() function throws some exceptions, when it failed.

But Objectify's put() function never throws any exception, as it is stated in Objectify JAVADOC.

Here is my question.

If Objectify's put() function doesn't throw an exception, how I can detect an error which may happen during exectuing put() function?

Answer (score 1):

Objectify's methods never swallow any native datastore exceptions.
(ref : http://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine/browse_thread/thread/e544de64fe9a61f)

But some runtime exceptions are omitted in API.

In this case, objectify's put() method throws exceptions which may be thrown by native datastore's put() method.

This issue related with omitted runtime exceptions is filed in objectify's issue page
(ref: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/list)